# Como posso tratar de datas de forma simples no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Preciso saber qual a diferença entre o tempo atual e um campo que eu puxo de um json. O problema é que está no formato de string e não sei como usar direito.

A string vem no formato RFC 2822 format - EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z

Answer (score 0):

Para trabalhar com datas o ideal é utilizar as biblioteca `time` ou `datetime`. Trabalhando com elas, precisa apenas verificar qual seria as equivalências para cada informação da data, você pode ver isso na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

O formato `EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`, em sua respectiva data seria algo mais ou menos assim `Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500`

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código que converta este formato em um formato de data padrão.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_format = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
dt = 'Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500'
dt_converted = datetime.strptime(dt, dt_format)
print(dt_converted)
```

A função `strptime` transforma uma **string que esteja em X formato** em uma data, os **parâmetros passados são a data (string) e o formato (string) em que está a data**

Comment: Queria entender onde está o erro pra terem negativado...

Comment: No te preocupes, en SO.pt [la proporción de downvotes es mucho mayor que en otros sitios](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8891/o-so-ru-e-o-so-es-t%C3%AAm-muito-menos-downvotes-do-que-o-so-mas-no-so-pt-%C3%A9-muito-ma). Algunas personas hacen downvote cuando la solución no es lo suficientemente original.

Answer (score -1):

No Python, você pode usar o módulo datetime para tratar datas de forma simples. Para calcular a diferença entre o tempo atual e uma data fornecida no formato RFC 2822, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

1 - Importar o módulo datetime.
2 - Converter a string RFC 2822 em um objeto datetime.
3 - Obter a data e hora atual usando datetime.now().
4 - Calcular a diferença entre as duas datas.

Aqui está um exemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Função para calcular a diferença entre duas datas
def calcular_diferenca_tempo(data_string):
    data_atual = datetime.now()  # Data e hora atual
    data_json = datetime.strptime(data_string, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')  # Converter a string RFC 2822 para objeto datetime

    diferenca = data_atual - data_json  # Calcular a diferença de tempo

    return diferenca

# Exemplo de uso
data_string = 'Mon, 28 Feb 2022 12:34:56 +0000'  # String RFC 2822 do JSON
diferenca_tempo = calcular_diferenca_tempo(data_string)

print(f'Diferença de tempo: {diferenca_tempo}')
print(f'Diferença em dias: {diferenca_tempo.days}')
print(f'Diferença em segundos: {diferenca_tempo.total_seconds()}')
```

Certifique-se de substituir data_string pelo valor do campo JSON que contém a string RFC 2822. O código acima calculará a diferença de tempo em um objeto timedelta, que representa a diferença entre duas datas. Você pode acessar os dias, segundos e outras unidades de tempo usando os atributos correspondentes do objeto timedelta.

Comment: Precisa fazer o tratamento para a timezone, da forma como está retorna o erro `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`